# Manually set a cookie in default cookiestore and using it in okhttp requests

Tags: android, cookies, okhttp, cookiemanager

In my android application, I am migrating to okhttp and need to setup the PHPSESSID manually for logged-in users in the default cookieStore, so that they don't get logged out. I am manually setting the cookie using the following code.

```
((CookieManager)client.getCookieHandler()).getCookieStore().add(new URI("http://www.example.com"), new HttpCookie("PHPSESSID", getPhpSessionID()));
```

The cookie seems to be set cause I can get the cookie back using this code

```
((CookieManager)client.getCookieHandler()).getCookieStore().get(new URI("http://www.example.com"));
```

However, when I am executing the client call using

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://www.example.com/getdata.php").build(); 
client.newCall(request).execute();
```

The cookies are not being sent in the request (verified this network call using android proxy).

Whats the correct way to set such a cookie so that okhttp client uses that cookie?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, and the answer doesn't help me. Did you get the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seem to be a difference between the `CookieHandler`'s `put` implementation of the `CookieManager` and the `CookieStore`'s `add` method.

By default if you use the `put` from the `CookieManager` it will add the domain and the path to the `HttpCookie` created internally by the implementation.  This will not happen if you use the `CookieStore`'s add method directly as you're the one responsible for creating the `HttpCookie`.

As it turns out `OkHttp` uses the `get` from the implementation which in your case will be `CookieManager` and not the `CookieStore` directly.  That `get` will also use the `path` to match the cookie which in your case will be missing.

If you don't provide the expected default path of "/" to your `HttpCookie` your cookie will not be found.

You should then modify your `HttpCookie` like so

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("PHPSESSID", getPhpSessionID());
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setVersion(0);
cookie.setDomain("www.example.com");
((CookieManager)client.getCookieHandler()).getCookieStore().add(new URI("http://www.example.com"), cookie);
```

Or to allow your solution to be more adaptable in the chance that you change `CookieHandler` implementation you could use the interface only instead of getting access to the `CookieStore`

You would accomplish this like so

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("PHPSESSID=" + "your_session_id_here"));
Map<String, List<String>> cookies = new HashMap<>();
cookies.put("Set-Cookie", values);
client.getCookieHandler().put(new URI("http://www.example.com"), cookies);
```

Comment: Great. Your 2nd solution worked.

However the 1st one didnt. okhttp still refused to set the cookie when sending network requests in this case.

Comment: Well I'm glad at least one of them worked.  I'm curious why the 1st didn't do anything for you.

Comment: In your first solution, by removing "http://" from the domain and adding `cookie.setDomain("www.example.com");` 
Instead of the usual cookie,
`Cookie: PHPSESSID=fq01rjn8f8jgotrf7egvcf7mu4`
The value that was set was this
`Cookie: $Version="1"; PHPSESSID="fq01rjn8f8jgotrf7egvcf7mu4";$Path="/";$Domain="www.example.com"`.

The server php file was not able to identify this cookie as a valid sessionid cookie.

Comment: @Udbhav try setting `setVersion(0)` on your HttpCookie when creating it. I think it's defaulting to version 1 and that might be the root cause of this.

Comment: That did it perfectly. Removing `http://` and using `setDomain('www.example.com')` and `setVersion(0)`, The network request are being sent as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't send cookies using both of your methods. I don't know what might be wrong. I found out that `client.getCookieHandler()` returns null, thus I check it first and create a new `CookieManager` before using your code.